# error when using \num command from siunitx package with an array from arrayjob package

Tags: siunitx, programming

I want to use the command \num from the siunitx package with some numerical data stored in an array data structure of the arrayjob package but I get an error message that I understand but I can't resolve.

here is an exemple

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{siunitx,arrayjobx,amsmath}
   \begin{document}
     \newarray\somevalues
     \readarray{somevalues}{1&2&3.5&4&5}
     \begin{align*}
         v_1    &= \somevalues(1)\\
         v_2    &= \somevalues(2)\\
         v_3    &= \somevalues(3)\\
         v_4    &= \somevalues(4)\\
         v_5    &= \somevalues(5)   
     \end{align*}

    \begin{align*}
        v_1 &= \num{\somevalues(1)}\\
        v_2 &= \num{\somevalues(2)}\\
        v_3 &= \num{\somevalues(3)}\\
        v_4 &= \num{\somevalues(4)}\\
        v_5 &= \num{\somevalues(5)} 
    \end{align*}
```

Comment: Sorry, but there's no way you can do this with `arrayjobx`

Comment: ok!!!  is there an other way to store data in a array form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way this can work with `arrayjobx`, because `\num` wants to see an explicit number (after full expansion), not a set of instructions to print one.

Here's a reimplementation of `\newarray` and `\readarray` with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_hafid_array_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
  \cs_new:Npn #1 (##1)
   {
    \seq_item:cn { l_hafid_array_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\readarray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_hafid_array_#1_seq } { & } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newarray\somevalues
\readarray{somevalues}{1&2&3.5&4&5}

\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \somevalues(1)\\
v_2 &= \somevalues(2)\\
v_3 &= \somevalues(3)\\
v_4 &= \somevalues(4)\\
v_5 &= \somevalues(5)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \num{\somevalues(1)}\\
v_2 &= \num{\somevalues(2)}\\
v_3 &= \num{\somevalues(3)}\\
v_4 &= \num{\somevalues(4)}\\
v_5 &= \num{\somevalues(5)} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use another package like, ok, let me think, hmm, for example ah yes [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\begin{document}
\xintAssignArray {1}{2}{3.5}{4}{5e100}{3.141592653}{2.718281828}\to\somevalues

\begin{align*}
     v_1    &= \somevalues{1}\\
     v_2    &= \somevalues{2}\\
     v_3    &= \somevalues{3}\\
     v_4    &= \somevalues{4}\\
     v_5    &= \somevalues{5}\\
     v_6    &= \somevalues{6}\\
     v_7    &= \somevalues{7}\\
     v_{1+3} &= \somevalues{1+3}\\
     v_{3+2} &= \somevalues{3+2} 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    v_1 &= \num{\somevalues{1}}\\
    v_2 &= \num{\somevalues{2}}\\
    v_3 &= \num{\somevalues{3}}\\
    v_4 &= \num{\somevalues{4}}\\
    v_5 &= \num{\somevalues{5}}\\
     v_6    &= \num{\somevalues{6}}\\
     v_7    &= \num{\somevalues{7}}\\
     v_{1+3} &= \num{\somevalues{1+3}}\\
     v_{3+2} &= \num{\somevalues{3+2}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However xinttools provides currently (xint 1.2g) nothing else to manipulate arrays like extracting a sub-array, joining arrays, etc... `\somevalues{0}` returns the number of elements of the array `\somevalues` as defined by `\xintAssignArray {..}...{..}\to \somevalues`. The entries are indexed starting at `1`.  One uses braces, not parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\check...` mechanism to save the recovered data in a macro, then use that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,arrayjobx,amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \newarray\somevalues
  \readarray{somevalues}{1&2&3.5&4&5}
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\ArrayNum[1]{%
    \ArrayNumAux#1\stop
  }
  \def\ArrayNumAux#1#2\stop{%
    \csname check\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname #2%
    \num{\cachedata}%
  }
  \makeatother
  \begin{align*}
      v_1    &= \somevalues(1)\\
      v_2    &= \somevalues(2)\\
      v_3    &= \somevalues(3)\\
      v_4    &= \somevalues(4)\\
      v_5    &= \somevalues(5)   
  \end{align*}
 \begin{align*}
     v_1 &= \ArrayNum{\somevalues(1)}\\
     v_2 &= \ArrayNum{\somevalues(2)}\\
     v_3 &= \ArrayNum{\somevalues(3)}\\
     v_4 &= \ArrayNum{\somevalues(4)}\\
     v_5 &= \ArrayNum{\somevalues(5)} 
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what does the \arrayNumAux#1 command do ???

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda It's used to split the argument of `\ArrayNum` into two parts so that no syntax change is required.

Comment: where to find some documentation on it ?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda It's just a macro I wrote in the demo above: the technique is a general TeX programming one